# Getting in a muddle with numeric primary keys

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key, primary-key-design

I hope someone can help. I'm trying to set up something along the below but am getting in a bit of a muddle. From what I understand, deriving a numeric ID variable (eg auto-incremented) for the primary key is more efficient that using a composite primary key of the 'natural' variables that define a record (especially if they're character variables (and more so if the collation is UTF-8))

As in the below example, each customer has a list of items (ITEMID) which are all members of a category (CATID), however, the problem is that I need customers to additionally be able to assign their items as a component of a collection set (SETID) which is a non-identifying reference table - any customer could have multiple versions of one SETID.

The items required for a set are specified by CATID. Therefore, in the example below which is for one customer, they could choose to assign Item 2, or 4 (or neither or both) to SET 001.

```
**ITEMS** 
ITEMID CATID 
1      04
2      02
3      01
4      02
5      05

**SETS**
SETID  CATID 
001    01
001    02
002    04
003    05

**CATEGORY**
CATID 
01
02
03
04
05

**Wanted result:**
ITEMID CATID SETNUMBER SETID 
1      04                   (customer chose not to assign to SET 002)
2      02    1         001
3      01    1         001
4      02    2         001
5      05              003
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like the "ITEM" table could stand to have a NULLable "SETID" foreign-key column.